# Caching of Included remote files in php

Tags: php

I am including a remote file after making

```
allow_url_include = On
```

The file is included using include_once in file.php

```
include_once ("http://abcd.com/func.php");
```

I am using simple LAMP stack.

My question is that for every request which comes to the server and uses file.php, func.php will be pulled from abcd.com. Within a request if file.php is included many times in other files will func.php be pulled every time?

Comment: If your include is **within** a function, then the answer is that it will be called every time the function is called.  If you call the function once, then it will be called once..  If you call the function twice, it will be called twice.  If it is outside a function and you are including just once, it will be called only once, and the php returned (albeit, the fact you shouldn't be getting raw php via a remote include) will be stored until the script has finished.

Comment: @Zak If the script file.php(which has include_once ("http://abcd.com/func.php");
) is included many times in other files which are used within the same request then will func.php be pulled every time?

Comment: No .. Because you are using `include_once`  Not just `include`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `_once` means you will load the file once per request. But will load it again on a new request. If you want to cache some response of this file make a `return` in that included file and save the result anywhere you like. For example in a textfile (i.e. as JSON-string). On the next request you check if that file exists.

However saving in a textfile may not be the most perfomant way to do this, but probably faster than requesting this file every time. Have a look at [Memcache](http://php.net/manual/de/book.memcache.php)

Include into a var:
`$data = include_once('...');` (include has to have a return)

`$data = cached_include('..')` (the function you write to get cached data)

Comment: can opcode caching solve the issue in a similar way? @Pilan

Comment: im sure there are several ways, but you cant use anything that runs only to serve the request, so no matter what you write in php runtime, will only last that long